# Validate duplicate entry in data extension and display error if duplicate other wise Insert into DE using smart Capture form

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, smart-capture

I want functionality in the smart Capture form in which if the user enters a duplicate entry for the same primary key then the page must display error in the same smart Capture otherwise  the record inserted into DE. For the same I have made a client side page for form and Processing page.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: I can't understand How to prevent smart Capture to commit Record into DE if the record is already present for a particular subscriber and add an error on the same page client page. I have made a client Page that has a smart Capture form which sends data to the processing page which then process and returns response to client page which on successful insertion window alerts